# Kendo Grid CustomEditor binding causes maxJsonLength error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have a Kendo Grid that has columns bound to a related table. The grid shows a fixed 4 level hierarchy that is flattened out: PK_Field, Name, Level_1, Level_2, Level_3 and Level_4.
I bind the Level Columns using [this examble from Telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom) :

Kendo grid:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyViewModel>()
  .Name("Grid")
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Command(command =>
      {
          command.Edit();
          command.Destroy();        
      }).Width(220);
      columns.Bound(t => t.Name).Width(80);
      columns.Bound(t => t.CreateDate).Width(80);
      columns.ForeignKey(t => t.Level1Id, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Level1"], "Id", "Text").Title("Level 1").EditorTemplateName("EditLevel1Id");
      columns.ForeignKey(t => t.Level2Id, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Level2"], "Id", "Text").Title("Level 2").EditorTemplateName("EditLevel2Id");
      columns.ForeignKey(t => t.Level3Id, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Level3"], "Id", "Text").Title("Level 3").EditorTemplateName("EditLevel3Id");
      columns.ForeignKey(t => t.Level4Id, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Level4"], "Id", "Text").Title("Level 4").EditorTemplateName("EditLevel4Id");
      columns.Bound(t => t.Username).Width(100);
  })
```

Server side:

```
private void PopulateCategories()
   {
       var dataContext = new SampleEntities();
       var categories = dataContext.Categories
                   .Select(c => new CategoryViewModel {
                       CategoryID = c.CategoryID,
                       CategoryName = c.CategoryName
                   })
                   .OrderBy(e => e.CategoryName);

       ViewData["Level1"] = categories;    
   }
```

The columns Level_1 to Level_4 each have their own `ViewData` variable.

When the amount of data used for Level_4 become large, the "The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property" error appears.

All my server-side methods are set to use `MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue` but the ViewData variables are not affected by this, and so they cause the error when they get too big.

How can I prevent large ViewData variables from producing the error?

**EDIT**

The editing templates -
Level 1:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
      .AutoBind(false)
      .OptionLabel("Select a value...")
      .DataTextField("Text")
      .DataValueField("Id")
      .DataSource(dataSource =>
      {
          dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("GetLevel1Descriptions", "MyAdmin").Data("filter1Descriptions"))
          .ServerFiltering(true);
      })
      .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "Level1Id" })
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)
```

Level 2:

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
      .AutoBind(false)
      .OptionLabel("Select a value...")
      .DataTextField("Text")
      .DataValueField("Id")
      .DataSource(dataSource =>
      {
          dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("GetLevel2Descriptions", "Admin").Data("filterLevel2Descriptions"))
          .ServerFiltering(true);
      })
      .CascadeFrom("Level1Id")
      .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "Level2Id" })
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)
```

Level3 and Level4 follow Level2 pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of things I did to resolve the issue with maxJson Length being hit:

1) Web.config changes:

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="50000000" />
   all other settings remove for Brevity.....
</system.web>


 <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />

      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    all other settings remove for Brevity.....
 </system.webServer>


<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000" recursionLimit="500">
          <converters></converters>
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```

2) Returned a custom version of the JsonResult object using these three variations:

```
protected virtual JsonResult GetLargeJson<T>(List<T> model, DataSourceRequest request = null, bool denyGet = true)
{
    JsonResult result = null;
    if (request == null)
    {
        result = Json(model);
    }
    else
    {
        result = Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }


    result.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    result.JsonRequestBehavior = (denyGet) ? JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet : JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    return result;
}

protected virtual JsonResult GetLargeJson(DataTable model, DataSourceRequest request = null, bool denyGet = true)
{
    JsonResult result = null;
    if (request == null)
    {
        result = Json(model);
    }
    else
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            DataSourceResult response = model.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            response.Errors = ModelState.SerializeErrors();


            result = Json(response);

        }
        else
        {
            result = Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        }
    }

    result.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    result.JsonRequestBehavior = (denyGet) ? JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet : JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;


    return result;


}



protected virtual JsonResult GetLargeJson<T>(T model, DataSourceRequest request = null, bool denyGet = true)
{
    JsonResult result = null;
    if (request == null)
    {
        result = Json(model);
    }
    else
    {
        result = Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    result.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    result.JsonRequestBehavior = (denyGet) ? JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet : JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;


    return result;


}
```

Where `type T` is a generic. This way I have a standard way of dealing with large objects and ensure they don't blow up an error.

I would suggest maybe looking at an alternative way of handling custom editing rather than booting everything in the `ViewData` object as that will become exceptionally large as you are experiencing and if the data is being used for drop downs/ multiselect type controls then using ajax versions of the controls may result in better performance in the long term. I'm happy to help with suggesting a cleaning way of performing this type of operation if you can give more details about the editing templates you are using.

Comment: @David_Shorthose: Thanks for your feedback so far. I had implemented the JsonResult overloads and the web.config setting as well, but the ViewData objects were not affected by those changes.

Comment: so debugging the code what is actually being returned/ stored in the viewdata? Are you sure it is just the level 4 list that is throwing this error? e.g. it's not another request being caught up in the error chain.

Comment: I can confirm it is the level4 object (a list of id and text pairs containing about 30k entries). If I lessen the amount of items in the Level4 object, no error occurs.

Comment: I would seriously reconsider loading these into the view data as 30K of data must be taking a serious amount of time to render. Also I am assuming at this stage based on the templating the options are not nullable? I would probably suggest moving away from the foreign key binding and using a normal Bound field that way you don't have to load the list of values into the drop downs. I am happy to move this into chat if you would prefer.

Comment: Thanks. I did get it right by binding through [Column.Bound] and changing the decidedly complicated viewmodel used by the grid to allow that. I will accept your answer as your comments provided the path to the solution!